# Why does my grep expression need to use $'string' to match tab characters?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, quoting

If you take this code:

```
echo -e '\t\t\tString' | grep '^[\t]*String'
```

the result is blank because it doesn't match, yet this:

```
echo -e '\t\t\tString' | grep $'^[\t]*String'
```

works. I swear that I must have used the first line's code a hundred times in my scripts and in the terminal, without ever using the "$" character like that, and it's always seemed to work. Has there been some recent change? Why does it need the "$" character? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As explained by @CodeGnome, "GNU sed perform their own expansion of escape characters, but GNU grep doesn't". I now realize that I had used sed previously without using `$`, and assumed grep worked exactly the same. Turns out it does not.

Comment: In that case, please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left of CodeGnome's answer. This will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### ANSI-C Quoting

According to the Bash manual, this is called [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting). The manual says:

> Words of the form *$'string'* are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

In practice, this means that `'\t'` will not be expanded into a tab character, but `$'\t'` will. The output should be equivalent to using `echo -e`, but can be used anywhere you'd use a string without requiring [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Utilities like GNU sed perform their own expansion of escape characters, but GNU grep doesn't. The Bash shell, not grep, expands escaped characters within ANSI-C quoted strings. Without the ANSI-C quoting, the regular expression you posted contains no tab characters to match the input.

Comment: *Utilities like GNU sed perform their own expansion of escape characters, but GNU grep doesn't* deserves emphasis IMHO: I can't believe I never realized that! [Hangs head in shame]

Answer (score 1):

You should probably realize that there's no single type of regular expressions.  There are at least `basic regular expressions` or `BRE` (sometimes only `RE`), `extended regular expressions` or `ERE` and `perl compatible regular expressions` or `PCRE`.  All those languages use slightly different syntax.  Current versions of `GNU grep` support all three and the `BRE` are default.  For `ERE` you need to use `-E` option and for `PCRE` `-P` option.  Your example will work only with `-P` since with basic and extended RE the backslash loses its meaning and `[\t]` matches either backslash or character t.  You were probably using that pattern in some other language that supports `PCRE` by default, which makes sense since they are the most powerful version.  Or perhaps you had `alias grep='grep -P'` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The first line works if you leave out the `^`. Maybe it worked but it didn't work the way you assumed? I doubt that `grep`'s behaviour has changed in such an important point.

`echo` does not translate escape sequences by default. You need the `-e` for that. Similar with the shell. You need `$'...'` to make the shell use escape sequences.