# What is wrong with using "\t" to grep for tab-separated values?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, tabulation

I have a .tsv file (values separated by tabs) with four values. So each line should have only three tabs and some text around each tab like this:

```
value   value2  value3  value4
```

But it looks that some lines are broken (there is more than three tabs). I need to find out these lines.

---

I came up with following grep pattern.

`grep -v "^[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+$"`

My thinking:

- first ^ matches the beggining
- [^\t]+ matches more than one "no tab character"
- \t matches single tab character
- $ matches end

And than I just put it into right order with correct number of times. That should match correct lines. So I reverted it by -v option to get the wrong lines.

But with the -v option it matches any line in the file and also some random text I tried that don't have any tabs inside.

**What is my mistake please?**

EDIT: I am using debian and bash.

Comment: Why not simply `grep` for lines with at least four tabs: `grep '\t.*\t.*\t.*\t'`?

Comment: @Philippos
I thought that my solution is more bullet proof. But you are right, your solution should be enough for most cases. But actually your solution also doesn't work for my file. It looks that the \t matches regular 't' characters... Could it be?

Comment: @Philippos Ok, so it was really that. \t cannot be used simply like this. Both solutions work great with -P option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825573/6372038

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my grep expression need to use $'string' to match tab characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168199/why-does-my-grep-expression-need-to-use-string-to-match-tab-characters)

Comment: @steeldriver not sure about the rules now. If I saw the question you are posting before posting mine, it would help me for sure. And I would be probably able to come up with solution. But it is not direct answer to my specific case.

Comment: @Philippos: "why not simply... ?" As far as I can tell, your regex is much less efficient than OP's, and involves a lot of backtracking. You could replace the greedy '.*' with non greedy '.*?', but it wouldn't be much more readable than the original.

Comment: @EricDuminil a sensible regex engine doesn't ever need to backtrack on that pattern because it knows that every `.*` ends immediately before a tab, so it need never backtrack into the *middle* of one, only to a different tab-position, which is either unnecessary (in the case that the pattern matches) or proven impossible by a fixed-string search (in the case that it doesn't).

Comment: @EricDuminil, on a quick test, the difference in execution times for a grep of those two regexes over a 317250-line file was about 9 % in favor of the original, hardly making the other "much less efficient". (On my Debian, with GNU grep, after fixing the regexes to actually work.) `.*?` is also a Perl-ism, and won't work in standard `grep`. The awk solution terdon posted half a day earlier runs in one tenth of the time.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks a lot for checking, and the info about '.*?'. 9% is nothing to sneeze at, especially with just 4 tabs. CSV files can have many more. For what it's worth, I find the original regex the most readable and straightforward. No tabs, tab, no tabs, tab, no tabs, .....

Comment: @EricDuminil, well, it depends, I guess. I was thinking that if those 9 % matter, then one is probably using a dedicated tool already, and not grep or regexes (given we can just scan the lines character-by-character and count the tabs here, and any other processing would probably be easier by splitting the fields first, instead of trying to figure out regexes for the full line). But what's hilarious is that switching to `grep -P` made it even faster than the awk, with `grep -E` at around 3 s, awk at 0.3 s and `grep -P` at less than 0.1 s, even without changing the regexes.

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks for the info, once again. It would be interesting to check with, let's say, 20 or 30 tabs.

Comment: @EricDuminil, hmm, increasing the number of tabs on each line looks to make it even worse for GNU grep. But it looks like there's big differences between regex engines. With a regex like `$'^([^\t]*\t){24}'` and 20 to 30 tab input lines I got about a 10x speed difference between Busybox and GNU grep's `-E` engine, and another ~10x between Busybox and GNU grep `-P`. With `-E` being slowest, Busybox in the middle and `grep -P` being fastest. And awk slightly slower than `grep -P`.

Comment: (I didn't check if some of those is the glibc implementation, or if GNU grep and/or Busybox have regex engines of their own. Also I didn't bother with different variants of the regexes themselves; anything would just get swamped in the difference between the engines.)

Comment: @ilkkachu impressive work. "Would get swamped..." I don't know much about regexen, but id expect the greedy version from philippos to backtrack a lot, possibly with exponential complexity depending on the number of tabs (?).

Comment: @ilkkachu: I just checked, with 5 lines, 30 values on each line, and 29 tabs in-between (https://pastebin.com/si0NPzYi). `grep -Pv "^(.+\t){29}.+$" test.csv` fails with `grep: exceeded PCRE's backtracking limit`. `grep -Pv "^([^\t]+\t){29}[^\t]+$" test.csv` and `grep -Pv "^(.+?\t){29}.+$" test.csv` both return instantly. With more lines but "only" 19 tabs, the `.+` version returns, but is ~10000 times slower than with `.+?` or `[^\t]+`.

Comment: @hobbs: If you're interested, here's a comparison between both regexen : https://regex101.com/r/ms7tYb/1 requires ~million steps. One tab more and regex101 returns a "catastrophic backtracking" error. https://regex101.com/r/634lCP/1 requires 500 steps, and would work with hundreds of tabs.

Comment: @EricDuminil no, that's a comparison of two regexes that are both *different* from the ones that were under discussion. You added capturing and a quantifier, which turns something that would have been okay into something disastrously stupid.

Comment: @hobbs No need for derogatory remarks. My point still stands without capturing group or quantifiers, which were only used for quick experimenting. Feel free to try with https://regex101.com/r/ms7tYb/2 and https://regex101.com/r/634lCP/2 , then. The difference in performance is the same as with quantifiers, and their structure is the same as the original regexen. https://regex101.com/r/65iUMi/1 still leads to "catastrophic backtracking", without any capturing group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others pointed out already `\t` in a regex does not stand for TAB.
So the obvious solution would be to add a literal TAB character, which BASH may make a bit tricky.
However you can enter a literal TAB using `^V` (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>).

Maybe it's more convenient to set `TAB='`<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>`'`.
The other thing is that `+` is treated literally in non-extended regular expressions (BRE) (see "*Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions*" in `man grep`), so use:

```bash
grep -v "^[^$TAB]\+$TAB[^$TAB]\+$TAB[^$TAB]\+$TAB[^$TAB]\+$"
```

(Here you could also shorten the variable to just `T`, and it's not necessary to use `${TAB}` (or `${T}`), but be prepared for surprises)

Also when you prefer to use `egrep` you can use a repeated group like this:

```bash
egrep -v "^([^$TAB]+$TAB){3}[^$TAB]+$"
```

Comment: Or `TAB=$(printf '\t')`. Note that `\+` is a GNUism. The standard equivalent is `\{1,\}`. Or you can switch to ERE with `-E` and then use `+`. But here, maybe `*` would make more sense to allow those TAB-separated fields to be empty like the the `awk`-based solution does.

Comment: Or you can wrap the regex in `$''` to have the shell expand `\t` into literal TAB characters for you. You will however have to escape any backslashes you want to retain.

Comment: @TooTea: That's also a bashism, not necessarily valid with non-bash shells that are often preferred for running scripts.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE True, but OP's question is explicitly about Bash. Also, if you're talking about `dash`, note that it does support `$''`, just like [many other common shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371827/which-shells-support-ansi-c-quoting-e-g-string).

Answer (score 15):

As you already saw, `\t` isn't special for Basic regular Expressions, and `grep` uses BRE by default. GNU `grep`, the default on Linux has `-P` for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which lets you use `\t` for tab characters.

However, what you want is much easier to do with `awk`. Just set the input field separator to a tab (`-F '\t'`) and then print any lines whose number of fields (`NF`) is not 3:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF!=3' file
```

That will print all lines in `file` with more or less than three fields. To limit to only more than three fields, use:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF>3' file
```

Comment: standard ERE doesn't support `\t` for a tab either (and neither does GNU as far as I can tell, though it supports _some_ of the Perl backslash-letter escapes). `[\t]` matches a backslash or the letter `t` in standard BRE or ERE.

Comment: Oh wow. All these years, I never knew that! I tend to use `-P` by default but I really thought ERE also handled that. Maybe because GNU `sed` does support it or something. Thanks, @ilkkachu, and fixed.

Comment: The behaviour for `\t` in both BRE and ERE is unspecified by POSIX, so what it matches will depend on the implementation. It may match on TAB, `t` (like GNU `grep`) or `\t` (like ksh93's builtin grep) or anything. `[\t]` is required to match on either backslash or `t` though  (though some implementations of some tools such as GNU `sed` are not compliant by default in that regard).

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> grep -v "^[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+$"
> ```

Here, grep will use basic regular expressions (BRE), since it wasn't given the `-E` option. Unlike in extended regular expressions (ERE), the `+` is not special in BRE and matches itself. Also, in standard regular expressions, the backslash is not special in bracket groups, so `[\t]` matches a backslash or the letter `t`, and `[^\t]` matches anything but those.

Outside of bracket groups, what `\t` matches is unspecified by the standard and in practice varies with the implementation. For instance, with GNU `grep`, it matches `t`, whilst with ast-open's `grep`, it matches a TAB character.

If you want to match a tab in standard regexes, you'll need to pass a literal tab to `grep`, e.g. with the `$'...'` form of quoting supported by many shells. (Though that's not standard either (yet); you'd have to use `printf` in a standard shell to get the tab character.)

So `grep $'a\tb'` would look for `a` and `b` separated by a tab, and `grep $'a\t\t*b'` or `grep $'a\t\\{1,\\}b'` or `grep -E $'a\t+b'` would look for `a` and `b` separated by at least one tab.

Comment: Re: you'll need to pass a literal tab to `grep` - easiest way to do this in Linux is ctrl-v followed by tab; no need for `$''`.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica, well "easiest" is up to opinion anyway, but I rather like using `$'\t'` over a hard tab because you can see it's a tab and not just a pile of spaces. Also tabs sometimes break when copypasting, and e.g. SE's editors destroys them. That Ctrl-V is a shell thing (not Linux), and depending on the shell it might not be supported or required, though almost all shells I tried support it. (but not Busybox, which does support `$'...'` though). And if you're writing a script in a separate file, you might well be able to just hit tab to get the character, but that's up to your editor.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so I find out the issue. I cannot use **\t** in grep like this. It just matches normal letter **t** .

Options how to match tab char are visible in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825552/6372038).

I solved my case by adding -P option to my command, so this works:

```
grep -Pv "^[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+$"
```

Another option was pointed by [@Philippos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/216004/philippos) in comments (just matching lines with at least four tabs). It also needs -P option though:

```
grep -P '\t.*\t.*\t.*\t'
```

Comment: `^[^\t]+(\t[^\t]+){3}$`

Comment: Indeed, thanks @StéphaneChazelas. Ilkachu already educated me on that, I tend to use `-P` by default so I assumed.

Comment: Note that the `'\t.*\t.*\t.*\t'` version would fail with more tabs. `^[^\t]+(\t[^\t]+){100}$` should still work fine.